# How to have a logout button with no login page in react-admin?

Tags: authentication, logout, react-admin

I need to have a logout button , but no need to have a login page.
so in react-admin documentation https://marmelab.com/react-admin/Admin.html#loginpage , says that for no login route, `loginPage={false}`.
when you do it the whole document gone away.

Answer (score 1):

You can see an example here:
https://marmelab.com/react-admin/Authentication.html#customizing-the-login-and-logout-components

```
// MyLogoutButton.js

import React, { forwardRef } from 'react';
import { useLogout } from 'react-admin';
import MenuItem from '@material-ui/core/MenuItem';
import ExitIcon from '@material-ui/icons/PowerSettingsNew';

const MyLogoutButton = forwardRef((props, ref) => {
    const logout = useLogout();
    const handleClick = () => logout();
    return (
        <MenuItem
            onClick={handleClick}
            ref={ref}
        >
            <ExitIcon /> Logout
        </MenuItem>
    );
});

export default MyLogoutButton;
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to specify an authProvider first.

The authProvider prop gives you a default login page and a default logout button. Once you have an authProvider, the logout button will automatically appear. Then you can disable the default login page by making it false as mentioned in the documentation.

You can do something like:

```
const App = () => (
    <Admin loginPage={false} authProvider={authProvider}>
    ...
    </Admin>
);
```